# any alternative to celery for background tasks in python

Tags: python, celery

I'm using flask and I was looking for any alternative in python which works like celery.

For eg:

```
@app.route('/')
def loop():
    for i in range(1000000):
        print(str(i))
        sys.stdout.write(str(i)+ '\n')
    return "done"
```

instead of :

```
@celery.task(name="loop")
and
loop.delay()
```

Is there any python code I can use to achieve the same result instead of installing celery?

Btw,
I tried :

```
 download_thread = threading.Thread(target=loop)
        download_thread.start()
```

But, I cannot see the data printed on console or anywhere on screen.

Comment: http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html This is a good choice for background tasks.

Comment: @Sraw Please can you write the code for the function above in apscheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it this way:

```
def foo():
    for i in range(1000000):
        print(str(i))
        sys.stdout.write(str(i)+ '\n')

@app.route('/')
def loop():
    download_thread = threading.Thread(target=foo)
    download_thread.start()
```